# What is the role of the isDummy method in Magento

Tags: magento-1.8

In the class/method \Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Order::prepareCreditmemo
There is this code

```
 /**
 * Prepare order creditmemo based on order items and requested params
 *
 * @param array $data
 * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Creditmemo
 */
public function prepareCreditmemo($data = array())
{
    $totalQty = 0;
    $creditmemo = $this->_convertor->toCreditmemo($this->_order);
    $qtys = isset($data['qtys']) ? $data['qtys'] : array();
    $this->updateLocaleNumbers($qtys);

    foreach ($this->_order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {
        if (!$this->_canRefundItem($orderItem, $qtys)) {
            continue;
        }

        $item = $this->_convertor->itemToCreditmemoItem($orderItem);
        if ($orderItem->isDummy()) {
            $qty = 1;
            $orderItem->setLockedDoShip(true);
        } else {
            if (isset($qtys[$orderItem->getId()])) {
                $qty = (float) $qtys[$orderItem->getId()];
            } elseif (!count($qtys)) {
                $qty = $orderItem->getQtyToRefund();
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        $totalQty += $qty;
        $item->setQty($qty);
        $creditmemo->addItem($item);
    }
    $creditmemo->setTotalQty($totalQty);

    $this->_initCreditmemoData($creditmemo, $data);

    $creditmemo->collectTotals();
    return $creditmemo;
}
```

If the `$orderItem->isDummy()` is true the `$qty` is set to 1.

Can someone please explain the reason behind this logic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When adding a configurable product to the cart, Magento actually adds 2 records to the `sale_quote_item` table.
One is the actual simple product and one is the configurable product to make it easier to calculate discount rules and maybe others.
That dummy item is not a real item, it's just there to make the dev live easier.
it's price is not sent to the payment providers or shipping carriers.

Comment: you are genius with core magento. Thanks for sharing ... @marius

Comment: Thank you Marius, can you tell me why the QTY is hard coded to 1 when the item is a dummy?

Comment: That I don't know.

Comment: I think you got this the wrong way around. It looks like the simple product is the dummy and the base product (configurable/bundle/whatever) is the "real" one.